# Yii, User Name Acting As Admin Even If Not Logged

Tags: php, yii

i have a problem. i was trying to make a checkAccess rule in the layout on my custom theme. but after deciding to keep it in the way it was before, i undo everything but now its staying logged as admin, even when i click logout and still rendering the stuff i dont want to show if not logged.. this is my main layout custom:

```
<?php
    if(Yii::app()->user->name = 'admin')
    {       
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavBar',array(
                    'brandLabel'=>TbHtml::b(Yii::app()->name),
                    'color'=>TbHtml::NAVBAR_COLOR_INVERSE,
                    'items'=>array(
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
                                    'items'=>array(
                                            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                                            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                                            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                                            array('label'=>'Users', 'url'=>array('/user/index')),
                                    ),
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
                                    'items'=>array(
                                            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                                            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )); 
    }
    else
    {
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavBar',array(
                    'brandLabel'=>TbHtml::b(Yii::app()->name),
                    'color'=>TbHtml::NAVBAR_COLOR_INVERSE,
                    'items'=>array(
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
                                    'items'=>array(
                                            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                                            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                                            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                                    ),
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
                                    'items'=>array(
                                            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                                            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ));
    } 
    ?>
```

i do an echo on the menu to show the name of the current logged user, but still returning as admin.. i dont know what is it doing.. this is my controller.

```
<?php

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
            return array(
                    'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
                    'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
            );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
            return array(
                    array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                            'actions'=>array('create', 'new'),
                            'users'=>array('*'),
                    ),
                    array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                            'users'=>array('@'),
                    ),
                    array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                            'actions'=>array('index', 'view', 'admin', 'delete'),
                            'users'=>array('admin'),
                    ),
                    array('deny',  // deny all users
                            'users'=>array('*'),
                    ),
            );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
            $this->render('view',array(
                    'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
            ));
    }

    public function actionNew($id)
    {
            $this->render('new',array(
                    'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
            ));
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
            $user = new User;
            $gunwcuser =new Gunwcuser;
            $game = new Game;
            $cash = new Cash;

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            $auth = '1';
            $time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
            $gp = '1000';
            $gold = '200000';
            $cash1 = '10000';
            $rank = '19';

            if(isset($_POST['User']))
            {


                    // Set data column in DB before saving
                    $user->Status = '1';
                    $user->MuteTime = $time;
                    $user->RestrictTime = $time;
                    $user->Authority = $auth;
                    $user->User_Level = '1';
                    $user->Authority2 = $auth;
                    $user->attributes=$_POST['User'];


                    $gunwcuser->Status = '1';
                    $gunwcuser->MuteTime = $time;
                    $gunwcuser->RestrictTime = $time;
                    $gunwcuser->Authority = $auth;
                    $gunwcuser->User_Level = '1';
                    $gunwcuser->Authority2 = $auth;
                    $gunwcuser->AuthorityBackup = $auth;
                    $gunwcuser->attributes=$_POST['User'];

                    $game->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                    $game->Nickname = $user->NickName;
                    $game->Money = $gold;
                    $game->EventScore1 = '0';
                    $game->EventScore2 = '0';
                    $game->EventScore3 = '0';
                    $game->AvatarWear = '0';
                    $game->Prop1 = '0';
                    $game->Prop2 = '0';
                    $game->AdminGift = $gp;
                    $game->TotalScore = $gp;
                    $game->SeasonScore = $rank;
                    $game->TotalGrade = $rank;
                    $game->SeasonGrade = '0';
                    $game->TotalRank = '0';
                    $game->SeasonRank = '0';
                    $game->AccumShot = '0';
                    $game->AccumDamage = '0';
                    $game->StageRecords = '0';
                    $game->LastUpdateTime = $time;
                    $game->NoRankUpdate = '0';
                    $game->ClientData = '0';
                    $game->CountryGrade = '20';
                    $game->CountryRank = '0';
                    $game->GiftProhibitTime = $time;

                    $cash->Cash = $cash1;

                    if($user->save() && $gunwcuser->save() && $game->save() && $cash->save())
                            /*$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$user->Id, 'message'=>$message));*/
                            $this->redirect(array('new', 'id'=>$user->Id));
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                    'user'=>$user, 'gunwcuser'=>$gunwcuser, 'game'=>$game, 'cash'=>$cash,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if(isset($_POST['User']))
            {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                    if($model->save())
                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->Id));
            }

            $this->render('update',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User');
            $this->render('index',array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
            $model=new User('search');
            $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
            if(isset($_GET['User']))
                    $model->attributes=$_GET['User'];

            $this->render('admin',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return User the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
            $model=User::model()->findByPk($id);
            if($model===null)
                    throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
            return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param User $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
            {
                    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                    Yii::app()->end();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Yii::app()->user->name = 'admin')
```

should be

```
if(Yii::app()->user->name == 'admin')
```

See == is comparing, = is setting :)

Also this thing

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
    'actions'=>array('create', 'new'),
    'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

Maybe the comments are just wrong, but it's now allowing create and new actions :)

Comment: sorry about the comments, this was made by gii and i edited the file, i changed the condition with the one you said, somehow it stopped doing the bug, thanks anyways